# How to show data of a single id using Vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm displaying all records on a page at this URI `xxx.test/employer/search/filter-by`. I'm using Algolia Search to display all of the records/results. I added a button called `View Profile` and attached an empty method to it called `showProfile`.

When a user clicks on this button, I want to display this specific profile/record on a new page by itself. If I was fetching data on my own, i.e. without Algolia's code I would be able to do this, but in this case I'm not really sure how to do this.

EmployerSearchComponent.vue:

```
<ais-instant-search
            :search-client="searchClient"
            index-name="candidate_profiles"
        >
            <ais-search-box v-model="query" class="mb-3" placeholder="Search by job title, company name or city..." />
            <ais-configure
                :restrictSearchableAttributes="['job_title', 'employment_type']"
                :hitsPerPage="25"
            />
            <b-row class="job-search-card">
                <ais-hits class="w-100">

                    <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
                        <b-col cols="12" class="mb-3">
                            <b-card>
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <a href="#" v-on:click="showProfile()" class="apply-job-btn btn btn-radius theme-btn apply-it" data-post-id="457" data-user-id="1" title="Apply this job"><i class="flaticon-paper-plane"></i> View Profile</a>
                                </div>
                                <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><router-link to="/">{{item.job_title}}</router-link></h4>
                                <p>Type: {{item.employment_type}}</p>
                                <b-card-text class="mt-2"><span v-if="item.experience && item.experience.length < 300">{{item.experience}}</span><span v-else>{{item.experience && item.experience.substring(0,300)+"..."}}</span></b-card-text>
                            </b-card>
                        </b-col>
                    </template>

                </ais-hits>

                <ais-pagination />
            </b-row>
        </ais-instant-search>
```

If I click on the network tab in the console, and on the algolia query search URI, I can see that the search results are in results[0].hits. Below is a screenshot of this data.

[image]

P.S. My data is empty it just contains algolia client ID's.

How can I display a single id on a new page? I understand that I need to get the id from the record that is being displayed, and show this information on a new page, but I don't know how to put it all together.

Again I think I'll need a route, so I created this
`Route::get('/employer/search/filter-by/show/{id}', 'EmployerSearchController@show')->name('employer.search.show');`

I'm using Laravel for my backend. Thanks in advance.

------------------------------------- UPDATED: -------------------------------------

I feel like I'm really close, but $itemId in my controller after I die and dump returns "undefined" for some reason.

router.js (Vue Router):

```
{
                path: '/employer/search/filter-by/:itemId/show',
                name: 'employer-search-index',
                component: SearchIndex,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Search Candidates',
                    requiresAuthEmployer: true,
                    employerHasPaid: true
                },
            },
```

EmployerSearchComponent.vue - with the `<router-link>` button:

```
<template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
    <b-col cols="12" class="mb-3">
        <b-card>
            <div class="float-right">
                <router-link class="apply-job-btn btn btn-radius theme-btn apply-it" :to="'/employer/search/filter-by/' + item.id + '/show'">View Profile</router-link>
            </div>

            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><router-link to="/">{{item.job_title}}</router-link></h4>
            <p>Type: {{item.employment_type}}</p>
            <b-card-text class="mt-2"><span v-if="item.experience && item.experience.length < 300">{{item.experience}}</span><span v-else>{{item.experience && item.experience.substring(0,300)+"..."}}</span></b-card-text>
        </b-card>
    </b-col>
</template>
```

EmployerSearchController.php:

```
public function show ($itemId)
    {
        $candidateProfiles = CandidateProfile::with(['user', 'photo', 'resume', 'video'])
        ->where('id', '=', $itemId)->get();

        return Response::json(array(
            'candidateProfiles' => $candidateProfiles,
        ), 200);

    }
```

api.php:

```
Route::get('/employer/search/filter-by/{itemId}/show', 'EmployerSearchController@show')->name('employer.search.show');
```

And Finally, in the .vue file that shows the Full Single Profile, I'm loading the data like this.

```
mounted() {
            this.loadCandidateProfileData();
        },

methods: {
    loadCandidateProfileData: async function () {
        try {
            const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData();
            this.candidateProfiles = response.data.candidateProfiles;

        } catch (error) {
            this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
        }
    },
}
```

And the employerService.js file from the above code:

```
export function loadCandidateProfileData(itemId, data) {
    return http().get(`employer/search/filter-by/${itemId}/show`, data);
}
```

Comment: you can pass the item id by parameter to the next view https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes  and then in the hook mounted of your next view make the query to bring all the data you want to show

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm confused about, I'm not sure how to pass the item id to the next view, even with the link you provided.

Comment: Are you using Vue router in your app (i.e. is it an SPA?) or are you displaying the search component in a blade template?

Comment: I'm building an SPA using Vue-Router, Vuex and Laravel passport for authentication.

Comment: when you declare your route details page you have to declare the parameter too like this:  { path: '/job/:id', component: JobDetails }, now in your JobDetails component mounted hook you can get the id:  $route.params.id

Comment: Itamar Garcia I updated my answer towards the bottom of my original post under UPDATED. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, you'll need an API endpoint to fetch the data from, returning it as a JSON object. You'll need to add a route to your client-side routes that takes the job ID (or slug) as a [parameter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). In your job component, you can retrieve the route param (e.g. in the `created()` method) as `$route.params.id`, for example, and use that to fetch the data from your API.

If your Algolia search is returning all the data that you want to display on your single job listing page, you *could* just put that in your Vuex store and display it without having to make another HTTP request. The downside of that would be that if a user bookmarked the page to return to later, there'd be no data in the store to display.

Comment: Hi Nilson, I updated my answer towards the bottom of my original post under UPDATED. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Hey Ryan, so the problem is that you're not getting the `itemId` param from the route and passing it to `loadCandidateProfileData()`.

Comment: Thank you I got it working. Just curious, since I'm building an SPA and using Vuex, how could I have done this without the itemId displaying in the URL?

Comment: When a user clicks a search result, you could fetch the full listing from your API, put it in your Vuex store, and have the detail page retrieve it. Though, as I mentioned in my answer, then you loose the ability to have a bookmarkable URL for that job.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Nilson Jacques responses. If you follow our conversation.
Finally I got the itemId param from the route and passed it to `loadCandidateProfileData()` like this:

```
loadCandidateProfileData: async function() {
                try {
                    const itemId = this.$route.params.itemId;
                    const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData(itemId);

                    this.candidateProfiles = response.data.candidateProfiles;

                    console.log(this.candidateProfiles);

                    if (response.data.candidateProfiles.current_page < response.data.candidateProfiles.last_page) {
                        this.moreExists = true;
                        this.nextPage = response.data.candidateProfiles.current_page + 1;
                    } else {
                        this.moreExists = false;
                    }


                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },
```